# Question about onClick but state not changing

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of items and I have a plus Icon next to each item. I am trying to add the item(which is passed down as prop from a parent component) into an array after clicking the plus Icon. So here is my onIconClick function:

```
state = { toggleIcon: "disabled", itemArray: [] };

onIconClick = () => {
    const { item } = this.props;
    const tempArray = this.state.itemArray.slice(0);

    if (this.state.toggleIcon === "disabled") {
      tempArray.push(item);

      console.log("tempArray: " + tempArray.length);
      console.log("tempArraySummary: " + tempArray);

      this.setState({ toggleIcon: "enabled", itemArray: tempArray });

      console.log("Here is the item array: " + this.state.itemArray);
    } else {

      this.setState({ toggleIcon: "disabled" });
      console.log("Cancel Selected item");
    }
  };
...
...
// Applied Semantic-ui React here
return(
   <Icon className={`${this.state.toggleIcon} plus`} onClick={this.onIconClick} />
);
```

So basically what I am doing here is to declare a temporary array, and push each item into the temporary array after the icon has been clicked, and then set the itemArray state to the temporary array.

When I tested this code, the first time I click on the icon, on the console, `tempArray` added item successfully, but `itemArray` is empty, but when I click the icon again to disable it, and click it again to add the item again, `tempArray` now has 2 items in it, but `itemArray` only has 1 item in it. I can't figure out why on the first time the page gets rendered, the item is not added into the `itemArray`

Comment: I tried looking through and made some changes in code, but itemArray is still one step behind. Perhaps I didn't make the changes right, but my case is slightly different that the one you posted

Comment: You're logging the state immediately after calling `setState`. Examine it on next render instead.

Comment: oh, ok, so the item should be added in itemArray at first click, but it's just that the console.log will show me that next time when the component render?

Comment: Yes - the linked canonical goes into much greater detail

Comment: oh, that makes sense now, thank you!